# Efficient way of applying calculations on dataframes with different conditions and levels

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe in the following format, it is sorted by the dates for each item, which have a determined frequency:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
 {
   "date": [2020-01-01, 2020-02-01, 2020-03-01, 2020-01-01, 2020-02-01],
   "item_ID": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"],
   "quantity" : [1, 2, 3, 5, 2],
   "type": ["y", "y", "n", "y", "n"],
 }
)
> df

    date    | item_ID | quantity | type |
2020-01-01  |    a    |    1     |  y   |
2020-02-01  |    a    |    2     |  y   |
2020-03-01  |    a    |    3     |  n   |
2020-01-01  |    b    |    5     |  y   |
2020-02-01  |    b    |    2     |  n   |
```

Whenever I find a type `"n"`, I need to subtract the quantity of this row from the previous  quantity with type "y" (based on the date), but the quantity cannot be negative, so if the subtraction returns a negative value, its set to 0 and the remaining is subtracted from the previous quantity and so on.

For example, on 2020-03-01 item_ID "a", we have a type "n" and 3 of quantity, so we check the previous date with type "y" (2020-02-01), and subtract the quantity:

*3-2=-1*

as the result is negative, we set the quantity to 0 and get the remaining (1):

```
2020-02-01  |    a    |    0     |  y   |
```

then go the to previous date and repeat the process:

*1-1 = 0*

```
2020-01-01  |    a    |    0     |  y   |
```

This must be done for each item, until there are no rows with type `"n"`. The desired output would be this:

```
    date    | item_ID | quantity | type |
2020-01-01  |    a    |    0     |  y   |
2020-02-01  |    a    |    0     |  y   |
2020-01-01  |    b    |    3     |  y   |
```

I know I can achieve that by looping through the unique items (`for item in df["item_ID"].unique():...)`, then sorting the dates in descending order and checking each row to apply the criteria, but for a larger dataset (which is my case), that would be too much time consuming, so is there a more efficient way of achieving that same result?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following (using `groupby` and `apply`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01"],
        "item_ID": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "quantity": [1, 2, 3, 5, 2],
        "type": ["y", "y", "n", "y", "n"],
    }
)

# Convert the date column to datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

# Create a function to apply to each group
def adjust_quantity(group):
    # Find the index of the row with type "n"
    n_index = group[group["type"] == "n"].index[0]

    cur = group.loc[n_index, "quantity"]

    # Loop through the rows from the "n" row to the beginning of the group
    for i in range(n_index - 1, -1, -1):
        group.loc[i, "quantity"] -= cur

        if group.loc[i, "quantity"] < 0:
            cur = abs(group.loc[i, "quantity"])
            group.loc[i, "quantity"] = 0
        else:
            break

    return group


# Group the dataframe by item_ID and apply the adjust_quantity function to each group
result = df.groupby("item_ID", group_keys=True).apply(adjust_quantity)

# Remove the rows with type "n"
result = result[result["type"] != "n"].reset_index(drop=True)

# Display the result
print(result)
```

p.s. I assume here that there is only one "n" for each item_ID and that the dates are already sorted. You can adjust accordingly if these assumptions are bad?

Comment: Was ChatGPT or any other AI used in creating this answer?